# Win7-64 powercfg –lastwake invalid parameter

Tags: windows-7, command-line-arguments, parameters

The command "powercfg –lastwake" gives invalid parameter error, however powercfg /lastwake works. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you copied that command from a site that prettifies punctuation. Notice how the dash before `lastwake` there isn't a normal dash like you get from hitting the <kbd>-</kbd> key. (The program sees the different character and thinks it's part of a different and unknown parameter.)

The character in your command is slightly wider than the normal dash. On the left here is a normal dash, and on the right is your dash (an [en dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#En_dash_versus_em_dash)):

## - –

If you type out the dash version of the command or copy `powercfg -lastwake` into your command prompt, it will function as normal.